# How can you update label type in Jira using REST API?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, jira

I am having trouble adding a component to a label type in Jira.

```
import browser_cookie3
import requests
import json

cj = browser_cookie3.load()
url = ""

text = {'fields': {'customfield_xxxx':['test']}}

r = requests.put(url, json=text, cookies=cj)

print(r.status_code)
```

With the above code, I can update the label list. However, I need to achieve the following - The label contains[ ABC, 123 ] and I want to add component [ZXC] to the existing list. My goal is to have[ABC, 123, ZXC] but with the above shown code it updates to - [ZXC]

I did find that in editmeta there is "**add**" function for the customfield, however, I was unable to make it work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's typically against rest principles to allow a user to update the value of a specific field without knowing it's value first.  I think you will have to query the value of `customfield_xxxx` first, manipulate it how you need to, then make the above request to update its value.

Comment: Are you sure it's not possible? I know there is jira-python library which has such function 
add_field_value(field, value)
Add a value to a field that supports multiple values, without resetting the existing values.
This should work with: labels, multiple checkbox lists, multiple select
Parameters
field (str) – The field name
value – The field’s value

Sadly, I am unable to use this library due to authentication constraints

Comment: Are you certain that that Jira-python function doesn’t use multiple requests?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, however, in editmeta there are customfield operations which are ["Add", "Set" and "Remove" ] which leads me to believe that it supports such function. Also, someone did it in Bash in a similar manner [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Failure-in-updating-Jira-label-using-REST-API/qaq-p/612187).  I want to thank you for trying to figure out the solution! :)

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution

```
import browser_cookie3
import requests
import json

cj = browser_cookie3.load()
jiraURL = "https://servicedesk.companyname.com/rest/api/2/issue/xxxxx/"
text = { "update": {"customfield_xxxx": [{ "add" : "test123",},  {"add": "123Test"} ]}}

r = requests.put(jiraURL, json=text, cookies=cj)
```

This will add two users to an existing list, thank you all for trying to help